# how do I use getTheadThProps in react table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-table

I have this on my table render function:

```
...
const getTheadThProps = (state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
 return {
    onClick: (e) => {
         // do your thing
         // call old handler, HOW ?
       }
    }
}

return (
<reactTable
...
getTheadThProps={getTheadThProps}
...
/>)
```

The documentation talks about onClick: (e, handleOriginal), tried that, but handleOriginal was always being undefined, so the example on documentation doesn't work.

When I replace the click event in this way, the "normal" sorting mechanism gets broken (toggleSort - the method that toggles the sorting status of the column header never gets called). That's the reason of why I need to call the original function.

Comment: Using React Table 6.7.5. I want to capture the click on column header (the one that does the sorting) without affecting existing functionality.

Comment: Hi could you provide an URL to the example you're referring to?

Comment: yeah it's at https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme, search for "handleOriginal"

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. It looks like you can recover the column sorting with the following:

```
getTheadThProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => ({
  onClick: () => {
    // Do whatever else you need to
    if (column.sortable !== false) {
      instance.sortColumn(column)
    }
  },
})
```